# SQL QUERY - How to match two attributes with more then one outcome?

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Long story short, I am building an application that matches people who want to adopt a dog with dogs available in a shelter based on size, age, among other characteristics.

My query is kinda working but I am facing some issues when using CASES, for example,
The code below is just a part of the whole code to make it simpler:

```
ANI.IS_HOUSE_TRAINED = CASE  
            WHEN APL.DEMANDS_HOUSE_TRAINED = 'House Trained only' THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN APL.DEMANDS_HOUSE_TRAINED = 'Training is not a must' THEN 'No' 
            END
```

The code above basically says IF THE APPLICANT REQUIRES A "HOUSE TRAINED DOG" match him with dogs which are "HOUSE TRAINED",
The second option for the applicant would be "TRAINING IS NOT A MUST" and this person should match with both TRAINED DOGS and UNTRAINED DOGS. But I seem incapable of figuring out how to do it.

What I also have tried creating a third case as shown below but it also doesn't work since the second case is a match:

```
ANI.IS_HOUSE_TRAINED = CASE  
        WHEN APL.DEMANDS_HOUSE_TRAINED = 'House Trained only' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN APL.DEMANDS_HOUSE_TRAINED = 'Training is not a must' THEN 'No'             
        WHEN APL.DEMANDS_HOUSE_TRAINED = 'Training is not a must' THEN 'Yes'                     
END
```

Anyone who could help me?
How to deal with cases that have more than one possible combination?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question:

```
ANI.IS_HOUSE_TRAINED = 
      CASE  
        WHEN APL.DEMANDS_HOUSE_TRAINED = 'House Trained only' THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE ANI.IS_HOUS_TRAINED
      END
```